# How to Display Progress Bar For Displaying Html5 File From External Storage Device In Android Web View?

Tags: java, android, html

I am accessing HTML 5 File From External Storage Device my file size is little bit big in size and displaying in Web view control in android.I am using Web Chrome Client for that file display successfully but before displaying file the activity has blank for some seconds after that display so how to display progress till display file in Web View.pl help me as early as possible.

I am using this code but progress bar finishing and till blank screen taking some seconds for displaying file.

```
webViewHelp.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
    public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {
      progressBar.setProgress(100);
      if (progress == 100) {
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
      } else {
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
      }
    }
  });
  progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
  webViewHelp.loadUrl(urlload);
```

Comment: check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36539945/show-a-progressbar-on-top-while-loading-webview-app/36540076#36540076

Answer (score -1):

this is exact copy of [this link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html).

```
 // Let's display the progress in the activity title bar, like the
 // browser app does.
 getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);

 webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

 final Activity activity = this;
 webViewHelp.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
   public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {
     // Activities and WebViews measure progress with different scales.
     // The progress meter will automatically disappear when we reach 100%
     activity.setProgress(progress * 1000);
   }
 });
 webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
   public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
     Toast.makeText(activity, "Oh no! " + description, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   }
 });

 webview.loadUrl(urlload);
```

Comment: I am used this code but it till takes time to load.My html 5 contains buttons also so if i used web view client then button controls not displayed in html file...that's y i am using web chrome client...

Comment: reduce 1000 to smaller values!